# Closing a vba form gives a msgbox that "This action will reset your project"

Tags: vba

Whenever I am closing my userform, it is giving a message box that reads, `This action will reset your project, proceed anyway ?` While debugging through the code, it was found that as soon as the code execution reaches the `End Sub` line, this msgbox is triggered. Please help me find the root cause of this issue.

Other observations:

All forms are unloaded properly on termination.

No error popped up while compiling the project.

Please see pic for clarity

[image]

```
  'This is a general outline of what happens inside my button in First Form as posting entire code would be difficult.
    
   Sub CodeInsideMyButtonInFirstForm()
    
      SecondForm.ListBoxinIt.Clear
      SecondForm.ListBoxinIt.additem ("Some values")
      SecondForm.Show
    
    End Sub
```

Comment: I am not sure where in the code lies the error. So I would have to post the whole code which is impossible because it is a mini application. I was hoping it was a general issue or something.

Comment: I would start by *not* unloading the forms. Instead, just hide them.

Comment: Okay, lemme make that change and see.

Comment: Since the second form shows without problems, the code you posted is not so relevant, I think. Is there some code in the second form `Terminate`, `Deactivate`, `QueryClose` events? Does one of the both involved forms have `ShowModal` property `True`?

Comment: No Code in any events of `SecondForm` The `FirstForm` has `ShowModal` set to `False` and  `SecondForm` has `ShowModal` set to `True`

Comment: Please, try setting `ShowModal` to `False` in the second form, too. Without something to interact with Application or the other form, will not help, but not seeing its code it (just) is simple to be tested... One more thing: I suppose that the second form does something in its 'life'. I mean, it is not only shown and you try closing it. Is that supposition correct?

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked. Setting `ShowModal` to `False` on both forms worked. I wonder why it worked.

Comment: Yes, Inside the button code, some values are added to the listbox in the secondform,  and then towards the end, the form is shown.

Comment: It is simple, I would say: `ShowModal = True` does not allow any interaction with other applications. I was wandering myself how you could know that `End Sub` is the line 'raising the error'... In such cases, you should place a break point on the first code line and run the code line by line, pressing `F8`. But in case of `False`, even that it is not allowed...

Comment: Well, I did execute the code line by line and this message only appeared after the last working line. But I still don't understand, with what other application my form would be interacting. Is there any way to know that ?

Comment: In such a case it may interact only with Excel application (navigate between sheets, select cells, modify them etc.) or with other existing forms...

Comment: Okay. Once again Thanks much..... :)